# Reason why style attribute does not use the android: namespace prefix

Tags: android, xml, xsd

In Android what is the reason that the style attribute does not use the android: namespace prefix?

See how `style` doesn't start with `android:`? Anyone know why?

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I Love Android!"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Thanks!

Comment: Can you further explain your question?

Comment: I added an example. Maybe the answer will provide some deeper insight, maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles):

> Note: The style attribute does not use the android: namespace prefix.

The reason `style` doesn't use the android namespace prefix is because it is part of the stock XML attributes.

Comment: What do you mean by "stock XML attributes" here? XML standard per se defines no built-in attributes except perhaps "xmlns".

Comment: @aleh I believe it's an attribute that's handled specially by the Android resource compiler when it compiles the XML down to the binary resource file that gets included in the APK.