# why the style attribute of xml in android has no namespace

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

we know every attribute in xml layout file has a namespace.for example:

```
    <TextView
        style="@style/xxx"
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_photos" 
    />
```

the id layout layout_width layout_height text   attributes all have a namespace "android"
and why the 'style' attribute  do not have one?

Answer (score -1):

Inside a xml file in Android, in order to use the "android:" namespace you have to put in a line somewhere at the start:

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

"style" is not from there.

And more (duplicate): [Reason why style attribute does not use the android: namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603422/reason-why-style-attribute-does-not-use-the-android-namespace-prefix)